# Getting Actionbar Tabs to Stick on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-tabs

I currently have a MainActivity.java which should be the only activity class. Though in that activity class I have a nav-drawer which links to other fragment views.

Currently the main issue Im facing is implementing tabs under a fragment and making them just be available for only that fragment and subfragments. I ran my application and the tabs appeared, but they also appear on other fragments after I visit the TeamsAndDriversFragment.

In my MainActivity.java I have the following function which helps point to the fragments it will generate once someone clicks on them in the nav-drawer:

```
/**
 * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TimeAndScoringFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new StandingsFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new TeamsAndDriversFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new NewsFragment();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        // Create a fragment transaction object to be able to switch fragments
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment container view with this fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Here is my current TeamsAndDriversFragment class where I have an actionbar navigation with tabs:

```
public class TeamsAndDriversFragment extends Fragment implements TabListener {

private List<Fragment> fragList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);

    ActionBar bar = getActivity().getActionBar();

    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab mTeamsTab = bar.newTab();
    mTeamsTab.setText("Teams");
    mTeamsTab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(mTeamsTab);

    Tab mDriversTab = bar.newTab();
    mDriversTab.setText("Drivers");
    mDriversTab.setTabListener(this);
    bar.addTab(mDriversTab);
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Fragment f = null;
    TabFragment tf = null;

    if(fragList.size() > tab.getPosition()) {
        fragList.get(tab.getPosition());
    }

    if(f == null) {
        tf = new TabFragment();
        Bundle data = new Bundle();
        data.putInt("idx", tab.getPosition());
        tf.setArguments(data);
        fragList.add(tf);
    } else {
        tf = (TabFragment) f;
    }

    ft.replace(android.R.id.content, tf);
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    if(fragList.size() > tab.getPosition()) {
        ft.remove(fragList.get(tab.getPosition()));
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Not sure but do you change you ActionBar navigation mode back to ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD when you load the other fragments?

Comment: I don't explicitly change it. Unless there is some other process that would change ActionBar to standard.

Comment: Im pretty sure Im going to have to bind the ActionBar to the fragment layout instead of the main activity layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `displayView()` method simply remove all tabs from the `ActionBar`, this way you'll always have a clean `ActionBar` with the exception of the `TeamsAndDriversFragment` fragment:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
     getSupportActionBar().removeAllTabs();
     // ...
}
```

Comment: This worked on removing the tabs, but leaves a black strip where the actionbar should contain its missing tabs.

Comment: @Novazero Try also changing the navigation mode of the `ActionBar`  back to standard in the display() method.